# Remove the "Your Games" menu on the side of Facebook Desktop Version

Tags: facebook

Yesterday I played some games on Facebook instant apps, and now a menu has been added to the side which has a title "Your Games". I want to remove this menu, but there is no option at all.

**Note:** This is not the games menu in the side bar which can be easily hidden by the option "hide games". So I wanted to mention it that this is not that menu, it is a different menu which is not in my side bar, As I have hidden my whole sidebar. So there is now way that it is the part of the sidebar. it still shows up.

Any help would be appreciated.
[image: You can see what I mean in this image, the menu is not in the sidebar and it is another menu with no option to remove it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't provide native methods for hiding most of their side panels and other assorted annoying page elements, luckily there are  third party methods to do such things, a browser add-on I use and trust has many such options for hiding the annoying parts of Facebook you just wish would all go away. Facebook has complicated matters lately because they are introducing a new Facebook layout this month, but the browser add-on should still work mostly, its called FB Purity and you can get it here: https://fbpurity.com

Comment: but i wasn't able to find any option to remove that menu at all

Comment: try ticking the  hide "Game / App Requests" option under the "Hide Right Column Links" heading on the FBP options screen, I think it should hide all game related boxes in the right column

Comment: thanks a lot, now it's gone otherwise i had to remove it by inspecting and deleting it everytime.